# run java class from current folder

Tags: java

I have java class which is runnable:

```
java my.package.Test
```

Test.class is in folder `./my/package`

Question is how can I run this class if it's in current folder (no `./my/package` exists)

thanks

Comment: java Test -> this should do

Comment: java abc.Test or java Test will not make it, as well as -cp; This is because no folder abc exists. I can make it using custom class loader: run class A and it runs Test - but looking if exists easier way. tnx

Comment: @Gianmarco that is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your class is in

```
package my.pack; // package is not an acceptable word in the package path
```

then you **must provide the fully qualified class name** (with package path) to run it and that path **must exist on the file system (or in the executed jar)**.

---

*Question is how can I run this class if it's in current folder (no ./my/package exists)*

You can't if the class is declared as being in that package.

Comment: thanks, that I thought - just asking in case I miss something

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You can obviously run a class in current directory if it is in the proper directory structure with `-classpath` (or `-cp`) argument.

Comment: @MiserableVariable The question stated _no ./my/package exists_. If you have a class declared as being in that package, you need that directory structure to execute it.

Comment: @MiserableVariable If it's in some other directory other than the current and that structure exists then, sure, you can provide a full path with `-cp`, but I don't think that's what the question was about.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the question. From the remark "no `./my/package` exists" I had assumed that the directory hierarchy does not exist in the current folder but it may exist at a higher level.

Comment: @MiserableVariable Maybe I'm the one who misunderstood. These comments should cover both situations.